# Refresh subview using ajax and jquery in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

For my CI project I am using Codeigniter & Boostrap.
Now my structure is that i have divided my view into two parts :

1. _layout_main.php
2. subview

So in each controller I first load subview and then the main layout.

```
$this->data['subview'] = 'superadmin/users/index';
$this->load->view('superadmin/_layout_main', $this->data);
```

In my main layout I call the subview.

```
<!-- MY MAIN LAYOUT DESIGN NAVBAR ETC -->
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12"><?php $this->load->view($subview); ?> </div>
</div>
```

So i just want to refresh my subview and not the main layout i.e navbar and other main layout components.

How can I do this using AJAX ?

Comment: Can you show your AJAX call also as ajax will not refresh anything so it depends on you are returning from controller and what you want to refresh

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to solve your problem with AJAX you have to deal more with javascript or jquery. You don't have to call subview **< ? php $this->load->view($subview); ?>** instead you update this div with what you want to display.
1. create a controller(used for ajax call) that accepts a parameter to identify what to display.
2. $.ajax({url: "**< ?php controller_name(ajax) ?>"**, success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
3. The working is when you click a button ajax call to controller with a parameter mentions what to display and controller servers results, when the function gets the result div updates.